# Is it possible to insert data in MySQL from a SQL Server trigger?

Tags: sql, mysql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, triggers

A fun question for a Friday afternoon, no?

As the question states, is it possible to write a SQL Server trigger that inserts data into a MySQL table?

---

EDIT: Yes, I *know* this is basically a dumb idea and that the application should be doing it and so on. *But* this is a legacy Classic ASP application which we're transitioning to MySQL; and until we get rid of the ASP bit we really would like to be able to squirt data over to the MySQL system without touching the ASP code.

For there be dragons. Just mentioning it tends to make it crash.

Thanks all!

Comment: Yes, but why would you give that much power to your SQL server and (potentially) take that much time in a trigger? There're timeouts to worry about, authentication, etc. I think it would be better to put an insert/delete request in another module, then let it handle touching each of the databases it needs to.

Comment: Errr.strike that "_yes_." I _assume_ it's possible but I can't find any reference to it. I'm still sticking with my original thought that seperating the inserts into a separate module is the better way to go.

Comment: @Michael: I don't disagree with you - talking about triggers instinctively makes me seriously question the data model.

Comment: @Michael Todd - Because architecturally this is (believe it or not) the easiest point to grab data in a live system. It's ugly, I know, I know...

Comment: @JeremyMcGee Makes sense since that's the "last second" you can get the data before it hits the system, but isn't it better (theoretically, anyway) to try and do that earlier upstream? Separation of concerns and all?

Comment: Ah (after update), now I understand; you **have** to do it this way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to write data to a different database from SQL Server, you'd have to first create a linked server instance on SQL Server pointing to the other db (MySQL in this example) with appropriate credentials/permissions.

Comment: OK, so how would I go about this? (I'm a developer, not a database expert, so excuse me!)

Comment: SQL Server - Linking Servers: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188279.aspx

Comment: @RickNZ Thanks! That one looks perfect - we'll give it a whirl.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this would be to use SQL CLR. You could have a CLR stored procedure or function that accesses the MySql DB.